# Why Windows update tool for my windows server 2008 R2 does not show any sharepoint security updates

Tags: administration, installation, configuration, cumulative-update, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a SharePoint 2013 farm installed on windows server 2008 R2. now when I start working on the farm in November 2016, the first thing I did was to install the full CU for November 2016.
but after that, i did not manually install any updates. but the problem I am facing is that the built-in Windows update tool is not showing any security or non-security updates for my SharePoint farm.
here is how the Windows update tool looks like:-

[image]

so can anyone advice why Windows update tool is only showing windows updates and some malicious removal tools, while it is not showing any security or non-security updates for SharePoint? and I am sure there are many updates for SharePoint since November 2016. now as I know Windows Update tool will not list any full CUs for SharePoint,,, but it should at least show security updates for SharePoint... but in my case, it is not showing any update related to SharePoint (as shown in the above picture)? so is there something I can do with this?? bearing in mind that the Windows update is set to check for Microsoft products as follow:-

[image]

now if I am not having any problem. then can anyone confirm if someone installs November 2016 SharePoint CU, then till now (May 2017), there are not any missing SharePoint security updates?? in this case, this can explain why windows update tool is not showing any SP security updates for my farm, which have November 2016 CU installed??

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 2):

Likely you do not have the Windows Update option 'Give me updates for other Microsoft products' checked. That said, I recommend against using Windows Update for SharePoint updates as they require manual intervention post-patch, and it is always a good idea to test in a QA environment prior to deploying to production.

Comment: kindly note that i checked the windows update settings, and the 'Give me updates for other Microsoft products'  is checked ,,, but i am not sure why the windows update is not showing any security updates for sharepoint... although the last time i have applied an update for sharepoint was on Feb 2016.. so i am sure there are many pending security updates that should be shown on the windows update tool... can you advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

Your WSUS endpoint could be on a GPO and overridden. Which allows the infrastructure team to take over what updates are available to you.

Try to see by going to the Local Group Policy Editor -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Update -> Click on Specify intranet Microsoft Update Service Location

Comment: can you please adivce more on your answer ? as i did not understand it ??? and how it is related to my question ?

Comment: When you ask your server for windows updates, it usually has a server or url that it points to. The WSUS acts as a middleman and will return the updates that your company "approves" of. If applied, it could give you all updates, no updates, or some in between, all regulated by a team that controls windows updates.

Comment: so will check this ... for the server and update my question ...thanks